# audio.play on specific channel intermittently does not work? (in Corona SDK)

Tags: coronasdk

I have a problem that intermittently some audio for my game is not working. It can work fine for a couple of minutes but then suddenly go silent and not work for that channel.
Any ideas why? Any known issues?

Details
* using this particular channel for a few different sounds that can occur during the game
* swap use of sounds on the channel as need be
* I have put the following code in the game loop and everything seems ok when the sound fails...

```
        print ("Audio Active/Playing/Paused/Volume: ",
                audio.isChannelActive(Constants.AUDIO_SFX),
                audio.isChannelPlaying(Constants.AUDIO_SFX),
                audio.isChannelPaused(Constants.AUDIO_SFX),
                audio.getVolume(Constants.AUDIO_SFX)
        )
```

Code example of what I'm doing at various points, in terms of swapping use of the channel for different sounds

```
   if audio.isChannelActive( Constants.AUDIO_SFX ) then
       audio.stop(Constants.AUDIO_SFX)
   end
   audio.play(runningSound, {channel=Constants.AUDIO_CANOPY_SFX, loops=-1, fadein=10 } )
```

Could it be a timing thing? Is doing an "audio.play" straight after an "audio.stop" on the same channel an issue? should there be a pause before the play perhaps?

any other ideas on how to fault find the cause here beyond the print statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that stands out to me is you're checking and stopping:  Constants.AUDIO_SFX
but your trying to play on channel Constants.AUDIO_CANOPY_SFX and we don't know what those values are.

I would also consider trying it without the fadein.

Comment: sorry - but yes they are the same value (I correct this) - one main point from this however is it seems the "fadein" value was what was causing the issue.  I don't understand why, but I've made it 0 (probably just had a value from a copy/paste I did) and now seems good.